#  Can I save in mongodb Hebrew characters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, hebrew

I work with ruby on rails and  want to save in mongodb data with Hebrew characters.
How can I do this?

thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB supports UTF-8 out of the box, which means you simply have to encode your strings into UTF-8. Here's a few links you can peruse:

[MongoDB & I18n strings](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Internationalized+Strings)

[I18n and rails railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/256-i18n-backends)

and finally,

[Encoding strings in Ruby 1.9](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_string)